# "t." statt Zitatstrich als Quellenangabe

Tags: abbreviation

Ich bin in den letzten Jahren recht häufig auf "t." bei Quellenangaben gestoßen und habe mich gefragt, wofür die Abkürzung steht.

Als erstes gefunden habe ich es auf dem Imageboard Krautchan, jedoch taucht es auch vereinzelt auf sozialen Medien und sonstigen stellen im Netz auf.

> Dass es Bielefeld nicht gibt, ist eine dreiste Lüge.
>
> *t. Bielefeldbernd*

Kann mir jemand sagen, was diese Abkürzung bedeutet?

Comment: Ich kann weder eine Antwort auf deine Frage finden, noch ein einziges Zitat, in dem die behauptete Abkürzung verwendet wird. Kannst du bitte zumindest als Kommentar Links zu Seiten posten, die belegen, dass es die von dir behauptete Verwendung tatsächlich gibt?

Comment: @HubertSchölnast ich könnte versuchen in der Wayback Machine zu schauen, aber aufgrund der Funktionsweise eines Imageboards und des Faktes, dass es die Originalwebsite nicht mehr gibt könnte das etwas kompliziert werden. Ich sehe mich mal nach anderen Quellen um und editiere meine Frage

Comment: Wenn das ein Einzelfall war, plädiere ich darauf, dass es ein Tippfehler oder ein anderer Irrtum des Verfassers war.

Comment: "t. + irgendwas mit bernd" wird auf krautchan und kohlchan als eine Art Grußformel benutzt; eine Floskel zur Bildung einer Gruppenidentität. Ich nehme an, das es die Abk. für "tschüß" ist, konnte aber dafür keinen Beleg finden.

Comment: Kohlchan… Wieder was gelernt.

Comment: @Philipp Unwissen ist manchmal ein Segen.

Comment: ich vermute, es soll damit ein "Tag" angedeutet werden, also so etwas wie das "#" für Hashtag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

t. ist das Kürzel für das finnische Wort *[terveisin](https://defi.dict.cc/?s=terveisin)* was soviel heißt wie "*Mit freundlichen Grüßen*".

Comment: siehe auch [hier](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/t.), [hier](https://knowyourmeme.com/memes/t--2) und [hier](https://knowyourmeme.com/forums/meme-research/topics/33368-t) für weitere Hintergrundinfos zu der Abkürzung. Kann man noch evtl zur Antwort hinzufügen.